# Unable to pass data between two components using services

Tags: javascript, angular, service, components

I want to pass the array value from Search component to History component to display the history of the searches done.

I have written the code in this manner -

**search-page.component.ts**

```
 export class SearchPageComponent implements OnInit {


    constructor( private dataService :DataService) {   }


  githubSearch(username:any){

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  this.httpClient.get("----")
  .pipe(map(Response => Response))
  .subscribe((res: any) => {

   
this.searchResultObject = res;
this.allSearchResultArray.push(this.searchResultObject);

   this.dataService.changeParam(this.allSearchResultArray)


    resolve(this.searchResultObject );

});

  });
}

passDataToService(){
  this.dataService.allPassedData.next(this.allSearchResultArray);
}

}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
export class DataService {

  allPassedData: any


  constructor() { }

storePassedObject(passedData:any){
  this.allPassedData.next(passedData);
}

retrievePassedObject(){
  return this.allPassedData;
}


}
```

**history-page.component.ts**

```
export class HistoryPageComponent implements OnInit {


  historyData : any = [];


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  
this.historyData = this.dataService.retrievePassedObject()



  }

}
```

I am unable to retrieve data via this designed code.

Comment: ``allPassedData`` is a normal variable, not an observable. so why you are using next() method?

Answer (score 0):

First create subject in service and make it as observable

> data.service.ts

```
export class DataService {

  private allPassedData = new Subject<any>();
  allPassedData$ = this.allPassedData.asObservable();

  constructor() { }


  setPassedData(retrievedData: any) {
    this.allPassedData.next(retrievedData);
  }
}
```

Now set the data in the observable

> search-page.component.ts

```
 passDataToService() {
        this.dataService.setPassedData(this.allSearchResultArray);
      }
```

> history-page.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // for retrieval of data in history component
    this.dataService.allPassedData$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.historyData = data
    })

  }
```

Comment: Hi @ashish , thanks for the help. But the code doesn't seem to work. When I debugged the code, the processor is not going inside the  history-page --> ngOnInit() ==> subscribe function when I load the history-page-somponent

Comment: you mean history component is not getting loaded or something else? can you please explain it in better way?